# How to upgrade app in /system/app?

Tags: android

We've Android app 1.0 and make it in /system/app for the special ROM.

Now we have released upgrade version 1.1 of that app, after installation, the version is changed to 1.1 in App list in Android settings. But when I reboot the system, the updated version is missed, back in 1.0.

How resolve this problem? Any detailed introductions about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:
adb shell
su
mount -o remount, rw /system
cat ApplicationName.apk > /system/app/ApplicationName.apk
chmod 644 ApplicationName.apk
reboot

as far as I know pm install only updates user-applications.
If you are deploying the app from Eclipse or from another IDE (it is as far as I know the same thing as doing pm install) the app goes under data/app.

The app location now is /data/app/com.package.name-1.apk

After the deploying you can do
adb shell
su
mount -o remount, rw /system
cat /data/app/com.package.name-1.apk > /system/app/ApplicationName.apk
chmod 644 /system/app/ApplicationName.apk
reboot, for the changes to take effect

Cat is normally the same as copy or cp, but when you cat from the /data/app/ the original com.package.name-1.apk disappears (i guess android takes care of this automatically somehow)

You can test this by doing ls -al when under /data/app/ folder

Answer (score 2):

Increase `versionCode` before you update your app.

In fact, the latest version of your app is installed into /data/app, when device reboot, the device will check whether the old app(v1.0) should be updated or not. However, according to scanPackageLI() in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/PackageManagerService.java

```
if (ps != null && !ps.codePath.equals(scanFile)) {
    // The path has changed from what was last scanned...  check the
    // version of the new path against what we have stored to determine
    // what to do.
    if (pkg.mVersionCode < ps.versionCode) {
        // The system package has been updated and the code path does not match
        // Ignore entry. Skip it.
        ......
    } else {
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

You can find if versionCode is the same, old app will not update. So you need to increase versionCode in your app when you want to update old app.

PS: Replacing old app with new one using command line can meet your need but I really don't think it is good.

Comment: +1 I don't know why this answer was downvoted but it was leading the asker towards the right direction. If an app installed in /system/app is updated, it will have ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP, if however you have two apks, one in /system/app and the other in /data/app, and they have the same versioncode, or that in /data/app has a lower versioncode, Android will automatically remove the apk in /data/app

Answer (score 1):

because the app is in System/app so,you should use push command

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell rm /system/app/your.apk
adb push your.apk /system/app
```

to update it.

maybe you need delete it first.

Usually, if you push an app to system/app, and then install it into data/app, the app system/app only works after you reboot your device.
In case, you can check whether there is the app in data/app after you reboot your device.

```
adb shell ls /data/app
```

if you find it, you can delete it to make sure you don't have the same app：

```
adb shell rm /data/app/your-1.apk
```

Comment: Actually, I use adb push to install it

Comment: The app has auto update functions, so I can't remove it firstly. We use pm -r xx.apk to replace install all downloaded new app version.

Comment: I don't know what pm command is. But I can make sure the adb install -r only can replace the app temporally. You have to use the adb shell rm and adb push to update the app in system/app

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you have install your application to /data/app not /system/app

try to move this app to /system/app

Comment: how to move it? I use adb install to install it